# How to ignore spaces when comprising two VARCHAR2 values

Tags: sql, string, oracle, comparison

I am facing a problem with comparison,
I have no idea how to force oracle to ignore spaces

I have tried trim function and replace(column,' ',''), but still

even I tried to use to_char for both two columns

this the query

```
select 
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),' ','') x,
replace(nvl(COL_CRD_ID,'x'),' ','') y,
case when 
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),' ','')  =  
replace(nvl(COL_CRD_ID,'x'),' ','')  then 'y' else 'no'end z
from tb_sales
where
case when 
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),' ','')  =  
replace(nvl(COL_CRD_ID,'x'),' ','')  then 'y' else 'no'end ='no'
```

the data type for each column as mentioned below

- MEMBER_CARD_NO : VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
- COL_CRD_ID: VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)

below an example for one record

```
x       |y               |z
17140974|"17140974  "    |no
```

the second one shows double quotation mark when I copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like that the problem referee to ASCII and Unicode when use varchar2 its need to use char 'N' before replace like this

```
select 
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'), '\W','') x,
replace(nvl(COL_CRD_ID,'x'),'\W','') y,
case when 
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),'\W','')  =  
replace(nvl(COL_CRD_ID,'x'),'\W','')  then 'y' else 'no'end z
from tb_sales
where
case when 
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),'\W','')  =  
replace(nvl(COL_CRD_ID,'x'),'\W','')  then 'y' else 'no'end ='no'
```

if it is not work use `regexp_replace(coulmn, '[[:space:]]*','')` instead of `replace(coulmn, ' ','')`

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have just tried your changes, I got this error Error starting at line : 11 in command -
replace(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),N' ',N''
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: dear, there is no double quotation any more and the code is working, but the main problem is the values not equal due to spaces. what do you recommend

Comment: Do you want to use regexp_replace(coulmn, '[[:space:]]*','') instead of  replace(coulmn, ' ','')

Comment: I want to use any funstion that could fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes *and* spaces, so you need to remove both.  `translate()` is convenient for that:

```
where x = translate(y, 'a "', 'a')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5896f90dba987bd764a4aaaa493162de) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you for your reply. How can i use translate in my command, because I did that `translate(nvl(MEMBER_CARD_NO,'x'),'a "','a')` still the result is no although there is no double quotation when I copied it

Comment: @MaramA-zaid . . . I added a db<>fiddle.